# Which training instances are being subsampled in each iteration of XGBoost?

Tags: r, boosting, gradient, subsampling

The `subsample` option in `XGBoost` is described [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html) as follows:

> Subsample ratio of the training instances. Setting it to 0.5 means that XGBoost would randomly sample half of the training data prior to growing trees. and this will prevent overfitting. Subsampling will occur once in every boosting iteration. [default=1]

**Is it possible to access the list of training instances being used in each iteration?**

If there are N observations in the full training data and we train an XGBoost model with NROUNDS iterations, I am imagining an N times NROUNDS matrix with position (i,j) being 1 if observation i is used in boosting iteration j, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I want to investigate if the trees behave differently when specific (groups of) observations are being used. This is related to a research project on influential observations in tree models.